# CheckboxTreeview() - scale size of checkboxes, change colors

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, treeview

[CheckboxTreeview()](https://ttkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets.CheckboxTreeview.html) for Python's Tkinter is a remarkable class. Unfortunately on HDPI monitors (like my 4K TV) the checkbox can be hard to read:

[image: existing checkboxes]

How can the checkboxes be easier to discern on HDPI monitors? Can colors be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CheckboxTreeview()](https://ttkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets.CheckboxTreeview.html) uses stock `.png` images at 19x14 pixel size that can appear tiny. I created a function to make scalable checkboxes depending on font size:

[image: new checkboxes]

*Note I removed background selection highlighting in old program which was used before discovering CheckboxTreeview()*

The code is pretty straight forward and comments are included for ease of use:

```
def make_checkboxes(hgt, outc, fillc, chkc):

    ''' Create CheckboxTreeview(); 'unchecked', 'checked' and 'tristate'
        Parms: height, outline color, fill color, checkmark color

        Returns list of three PhotoImages for parent. How to use 4K screen:

            MON_FONTSIZE = 12
            row_height=int(MON_FONTSIZE*2.2)
            style.configure("Treeview", font=(None, MON_FONTSIZE), \
                            rowheight=row_height)

            self.checkboxes = make_checkboxes(row_height-6, 'black', \
                                              'white', 'deepskyblue')
            self.cd_tree.tag_configure("unchecked", image=self.checkboxes[0])
            self.cd_tree.tag_configure("tristate", image=self.checkboxes[1])
            self.cd_tree.tag_configure("checked", image=self.checkboxes[2])

    '''
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw       # Pillow image processing

    if hgt % 2 == 1: hgt = hgt + 1                  # even number box height
    if hgt < 14: hgt = 14                           # minimum box height
    wid = hgt                                       # square: width = heidht
    wid_pad = int(wid * 10 / 20)                    # lead + trailing padding
    xo = int(wid_pad / 5)                           # x-offset after lead pad
    retn_images = []                                # list of three images

    image = Image.new("RGBA", (wid + wid_pad, hgt), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)                    # Create drawable image

    draw.rectangle([(xo, 0), (xo + wid, hgt-1)], fill=fillc, outline=outc)
    retn_images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))   # Unchecked
    draw.rectangle([(xo+3, 7), (xo + wid-3, hgt-8)], fill=chkc)
    retn_images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))   # Tristate
    draw.rectangle([(xo+3, 3), (xo + hgt-3, hgt-4)], fill=chkc)
    retn_images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))   # Checked

    return retn_images
```

Comment: Nice, I expanded it a little bit to draw something like a real checked-icon. But it doesn't fit in the comment, so I posted it as new anser

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the given answer: This will draw an actual "checked"-icon instead of a rectangle. Final dimensions should fit the ones of the already given answer.

It would look somehow like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**  But you can of course use any color you like

```
scalingFactor = 10

imageChecked = Image.new("RGBA", ((wid + wid_pad) *scalingFactor, hgt *10), (0, 0, 0, 0))
drawChecked = ImageDraw.Draw(imageChecked) 
drawChecked.rectangle([(xo*scalingFactor, 0), ((xo + wid)*scalingFactor, (hgt-1)*scalingFactor)], fill=fillc, outline=outc)

startPoint = (xo*scalingFactor+int(0.15*wid*scalingFactor), (0.6*hgt*scalingFactor))
middlePoint = (xo*scalingFactor+int(0.5*wid*scalingFactor), (int(0.8*hgt*scalingFactor)))
endPoint =(xo*scalingFactor+int(0.85*wid*scalingFactor), (int(0.1*hgt*scalingFactor)))

drawChecked.line([startPoint,middlePoint,endPoint], fill=chkc, width=int(hgt*scalingFactor/5), joint="curve")

imageChecked = imageChecked.resize((wid+wid_pad, hgt), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Comment: Nice. But I think Google would use blue background with white cueckmark.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sure thing, you can ofc use whatever coloring you want. That was the whole idea of your original post I guess :)